# css "border-image" browser compatibility issues

Tags: css, cross-browser

I've searched for hours, and quadruple-checked my file for coding errors, but can't seem to come up with anything. Basically I have a div class on my website using a border-image code, which works great in Firefox. But none of the other browsers display it at all. It's probably a stupid code error somewhere, but I can't seem to find it, so I'd appreciate an extra set of eyes on this.

You can find the website at:
http://beta.lycancreations.com/

It's the .section div class, which is used in almost all the text blocks on the webpage.

```
.section{
    padding: 15px 0px 20px;
    -moz-border-image-source:url(../img/layout/border.png);
    -moz-border-image-repeat: repeat;
    -moz-border-image-slice: 10 10;
    -moz-border-image-width: auto;
    -o-border-image-source:url(../img/layout/border.png);
    -o-border-image-repeat: repeat;
    -o-border-image-slice: 10 10;
    -o-border-image-width: auto;
    -webkit-border-image-source:url(../img/layout/border.png);
    -webkit-border-image-repeat: repeat;
    -webkit-border-image-slice: 10 10;
    -webkit-border-image-width: auto;
    border-image-source:url(../img/layout/border.png);
    border-image-repeat: repeat;
    border-image-slice: 10 10;
    border-image-width: auto;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

I'm using the long version of the CSS because I keep messing up with the shorter version, it was easier for me to look at each property individually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, it's my first time posting here so please let me know if I forgot to include anything!

Comment: In which browsers does it not work? http://caniuse.com/border-image

Comment: It doesn't work in Chrome, Safari or Opera, which is basically all the browsers I've tested in so far besides Firefox.

Comment: caniuse indicates that Opera only supports the shorthand, not individual properties.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving `div.section` a border fixed it for me in Safari.

```
div.section {
  ...
  border:1px;
}
```

Comment: This didn't seem to help in Chrome.

Comment: I feel like an idiot now, thank you! It fixed it in both Safari and Chrome. Still doesn't seem to work in Opera though.